# when using spring autowiring then struts tag does not map with action class

Tags: spring, struts2

when i am putting autowiring interceptor(interceptor-ref name="autowiring") in the action tag in spring.xml then struts tag in index.jsp does not able to map with the setter of that action class. and when i am removing that autowiring tag from the action tag then in that case struts tag of jsp does able to map with the setter of the action class.

Any help from your side will be more than welcome. if you need any sort of example then let me know.

```
<s:textfield name="name" label="Name" />
<s:textfield name="salary" label="Salary" />
<s:submit value="Add Record" />
```

then this struts tag with name 'name' and 'salary' does not set the value in action class represented with the same name of setter/getter.

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setSalary(String salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

Comment: can you provide your xml code?

Comment: <action name="submitEmp" class="myaction.AddEmployeeSubmitAction">
     <interceptor-ref name="autowiring" /> 
     <result name="success">/addRecord.jsp</result>
</action>

Comment: i am not sure why you doing this??? you can do this simply in your code

Comment: but the thing is why would i am not able to do this way? why jsp is not mapping to action when i am using autowiring interceptor.

Comment: my question is why you are using this interceptor, if you are using spring-s2 plugin it will do the autowiring for you.Any reason to use this approach?

Comment: okay. actually i am using hibernate to persist my data to database. autowiring is use to inject sessionfactory bean in my action class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14054/discussion-between-ankit-and-umesh-awasthi)

Answer (score 2):

If you define an interceptor On an action you must define *all* interceptors on an action. If your parameters aren't being set then whatever the "autowiring" interceptor reference doesn't include the "parameters" stack, the interceptor responsible for transferring form properties to actions.

And Umesh is correct, if you're using Spring, the plugin handles injection for you, and you do not need to manually define the "autowiring" plugin on your action. If you just remove that interceptor definition, your parameters should be set as normal, and the action should still be wired up.

That said–using a session factory manually inside an action would not be considered a best practice. Any session factory logic should be wrapped up inside your DAOs/services/etc. Actions should rarely (read: never) be aware of the persistence layer.

Comment: Hey Dave thanks for you suggestion. i totally agree what you said and i am implementing this way only. i am using DAO layer in my action. and that DAO class need to be inject in Action through spring DI. and that DAO is one which is doing persistence in database. 

the problem i was facing is when i am putting the autowiring interceptor in between the action tag then default interceptors of struts were not implemented. and there i lost the parameters in action class

Comment: @ankit Oh, okay. Yeah, you shouldn't need to manually include the autowiring interceptor at all then.

Comment: if i dont include autowiring manually. then my DAO(persistance layer interacting with the database) bean wont be injected into action class. then how would i save the business object to database.

Comment: @ankit Then you're not using the Spring plugin properly.